# Rails - Gem Error while installing pg (1.1.3), and Bundler cannot continue during Netlify deployment

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, netlify

I am still fairly new to Rails. I am trying to deploy to Netlify but my deployment keeps failing because of this error.

4:23:44 PM: An error occurred while installing pg (1.2.3), and Bundler cannot continue.

4:23:44 PM: Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.2.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`

4:23:44 PM: succeeds before bundling.
4:23:44 PM: In Gemfile:
4:23:44 PM:   pg
4:23:44 PM: Error during gem install

4:23:44 PM: Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1

Comment: can you share your gemfile? or just the line where you specified the pg gem. Something like `gem 'pg'`

Comment: have you tried to do `gem install pg -v '1.2.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` ?

Comment: The pg gem needs a dev pkg. Which comes when you install postgres. Probably your local machine has this dev pkg and you deploy machine doesn't

Comment: You try `sudo apt-get install postgresql`  and   `bundle `